# How can fix this weird error in my simple C program?

Tags: c

This is a simple C authentication program that went wrong. It's reading the strings from the console as a username and password as input correct, but the username input has becomes blank space string. What might be the mistake?

#### Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char username[4];
    char password[8];

    printf("Enter username: ");
    scanf("%s", username);
    printf("Enter password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    if (username == "ojas" && password == "ojas1234")
    {
        printf("Access granted!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s and %s\n", username, password);
        printf("Access denied");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
Enter username: ojas
Enter password: ojas1234
 and ojas1234
Access denied
```

Comment: research `strcmp`

Comment: and both arrays need to be bigger. I would recommend at least 100.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, including:

- You don't compare C strings with "==".  You must use [strcmp()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) (or equivalent) instead.
- The combination of small character arrays and unsafe usage of "scanf()" is likely to cause buffer overruns.  You should define a larger buffer, and use a "safer" method like [fgets()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

SUGGESTED CHANGES:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING 80

int main()
{
   char username[MAX_STRING];
   char password[MAX_STRING];

   printf("Enter username: ");
   fgets(username, MAX_STRING, stdin);
   strtok(username, "\n");
   printf("Enter password: ");
   fgets(password, MAX_STRING, stdin);
   strtok(password, "\n");

   if ((strcmp(username, "ojas") == 0) && (strcmp(password, "ojas1234") == 0)){
      printf("Access granted!");
   }
   else {
      printf("%s and %s\n", username, password);
      printf("Access denied");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To compare two strings, you can use `strcmp()` function. This will compare the two strings character by character. Don't forget to use the header file `string.h`
   You can't use equal sign to compare two strings because string literals are identical and a string in C is a character array and it refers to an address. So if you use "==" signs, you will end up comparing two addresses.
2. Though the above mistake is corrected, still you will get the output as **Access Denied**. That is because your buffer overflows. So, define a large number for your username and password char arrays.

The below code might help you to fix these issues.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define LEN 50

int main()
{
   char username[LEN];
   char password[LEN];

   printf("Enter username: ");
   scanf("%s", username);
   printf("Enter password: ");
   scanf("%s", password);

   if ((strcmp(username,"ojas") == 0) && (strcmp(password,"ojas1234") == 0))
   {
      printf("Access granted!");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("%s and %s\n", username, password);
      printf("Access denied");
   }

return 0;

}
```